# maximizing the sum of probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

The definition of [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Definition) between two discrete, random variables, $X,Y$ is given by
$$I(X,Y) = \sum_{y\in Y}\sum_{x\in X}p(x,y)\log\left(\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)}\right),$$
where $p(x,y)$ is the joint probability distribution function of $X$ and $Y$, and $p(x),p(y)$ are the marginal probability distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

So, my question, how do I maximize $I(X,Y)$? It's not like I can just take the derivative of that double sum and set it equal to $0$...can I?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not clear what you are choosing. Once $p(x,y)$ is given for all $x$ and $y$ there is nothing to vary.

Suppose you are given $X$ and you ask which $Y$ maximizes $I(X,Y)$? The answer is $Y=X$. So the question now is which $X$ has the highest entropy (by picking $X$ about which you know least, you maximize $I(X,Y)$ by setting $Y=X$). And I think [uniform distribution is the one with the highest entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution).